# Airflow running but nothing happening

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

My airflow DAG is showing its running but nothing is happening. I am not understanding what's wrong? Spend lot of time with this. 
The first dag in code should set airflow variable and second dag should read this variable and run tasks based on the values in the variable. The second DAG runs 15 minutes after the first DAG. But always its showing its running.
Anybody please help. Thank you.

Airflow version 1.9.0[image]

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from utils.etl_fail_slack_alert import task_fail_slack_alert
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.models import Variable

project = 'asd'
source_dataset = 'dfghdfh'
destination_dataset = 'dfhdfhdf'
table_prefix = ''

default_args = {
    'start_date': '2019-09-10',
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=2),
    'on_failure_callback': task_fail_slack_alert,
}

def set_views_av():
    bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
                           delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    query = ("SELECT table_id FROM `{project}.{dataset}.{table}`;".format(
        project=project, dataset=source_dataset, table='__TABLES__'))

    df = bq_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=query, dialect='standard')

    view_names = df['table_id'].tolist()
    Variable.set('view_list', '|'.join(view_names))


def bq_operator(vname, dag):
    sql = ("SELECT * FROM `{project}.{dataset}.{table}`".format(
        project=project, dataset=source_dataset, table=vname))

    materialize_view_bq = BigQueryOperator(bql=sql,
                                           destination_dataset_table = project + "." + destination_dataset + "." + table_prefix + vname,
                                           task_id="materialize_" + vname,
                                           bigquery_conn_id="bigquery_default",
                                           google_cloud_storage_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
                                           use_legacy_sql=False,
                                           write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
                                           create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                                           query_params={},
                                           allow_large_results=True,
                                           dag=dag
                                           )
    return materialize_view_bq


with models.DAG(dag_id="materialize_init_views", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="15 09 * * *", catchup=True) as dag_init:
    bridge = DummyOperator(
        task_id='bridge',
        dag=dag_init
    )
    set_views = python_operator.PythonOperator(task_id="set_views",
                                               python_callable=set_views_av
                                               )

    bridge >> set_views


with models.DAG(dag_id="materialize_views_dynamic", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="30 09 * * *", catchup=True) as dag:

    views = Variable.get("view_list").split("|")
    bridge = DummyOperator(
        task_id='bridge',
        dag=dag
    )

    for vname in views:
        materialize_view_bq = bq_operator(vname, dag)
        bridge >> materialize_view_bq
```

Comment: **[1]** Which [`executor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L88) are you using? Is it [`CeleryExecutor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L88)? **[2]** What's the reason for non-execution + state of task(s) shown in [`Task Instance Details` button](https://imgur.com/a/Q7kYGCK)?

Comment: @y2k-shubham I fixed it by removing the BigQueryHook and adding pd.read_gbq function. I think airflow 1.9 has  some major issues. Thanks for your response.